# Arrange the date query result [oracle 11g]

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g, dual-table

This is my query to get all possible dates between two dates based on days.

```
    select A.presentationID,
       A.PRESENTATIONDAY,
       TO_CHAR(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta,'DD-MM-YYYY','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') LIST_DATE
from 
  PRESENTATION A, 
  (
     select level-1 as delta 
     from dual 
     connect by level-1 <= (
       select max(PRESENTATIONDATEEND- PRESENTATIONDATESTART) from PRESENTATION
     )
  )
where A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta <= A.PRESENTATIONDATEEND
and
  a.presentationday = trim(to_char(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta, 'Day'))
order by 1,2,3;
```

The values are retrieved from `presentation` table which consist of `presentationday`, `presentationdatestart` and `presentationdateend`.

Result from this query is :

```
622 Monday  02-05-2016 12:00:00
622 Monday  09-05-2016 12:00:00
622 Monday  16-05-2016 12:00:00
622 Monday  23-05-2016 12:00:00
622 Monday  30-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 03-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 10-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 17-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 24-05-2016 12:00:00
623 Tuesday 31-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   04-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   11-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   18-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   25-05-2016 12:00:00
624 Wednesday   01-06-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    05-05-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    12-05-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    19-05-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    26-05-2016 12:00:00
625 Thursday    02-06-2016 12:00:00
```

How can I arrange these value into something like this:

```
    622 Monday      02-05-2016     
    623 Tuesday     03-05-2016     
    624 Wednesday   04-05-2016     
    625 Thursday    05-05-2016     
    622 Monday      09-05-2016     
    623 Tuesday     10-05-2016  
    624 Wednesday   11-05-2016    
    625 Thursday    12-05-2016 
    622 Monday      16-05-2016 
    ....
    625 Thursday    02-06-2016
```

Comment: First use `to_char` to change date format as you want.
Second `order by 2, 1` instead of `1,2` as order by date then id to arrange your result rows.

Comment: Thing you wanted first is now different from what you want now. Let me update my answer

Comment: I changed my query in my question. However, I tried to change my order by clause... The result turned to be weirder. Wednesday 01-06-2016 is the first row. It should be Monday 02-05-2016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're just after this:

```
select   a.presentationid,
         a.presentationday,
         to_char (a.presentationdatestart + delta, 'DD-MM-YYYY', 'NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') list_date
from     presentation a,
         (select     level - 1 as delta
          from       dual
          connect by level - 1 <= (select max (presentationdateend - presentationdatestart)
                                   from   presentation))
where    a.presentationdatestart + delta <= a.presentationdateend
and      a.presentationday = to_char(a.presentationdatestart + delta, 'fmDay')
order by a.presentationdatestart + delta,
         a.presentationid;
```

N.B. note how I've removed your `trim()` and replaced it with [`fm`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm#SQLRF00216) in the format mask.

P.S. You could rewrite your query to remove the join condition (and extra call to the presentation table) by doing it like so:

```
with presentation as (select 622 presentationid, 'Monday' presentationday, to_date('01/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdatestart, to_date('31/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdateend from dual union all
                      select 623 presentationid, 'Tuesday' presentationday, to_date('01/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdatestart, to_date('31/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdateend from dual union all
                      select 624 presentationid, 'Wednesday' presentationday, to_date('01/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdatestart, to_date('07/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdateend from dual union all
                      select 625 presentationid, 'Thursday' presentationday, to_date('01/05/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdatestart, to_date('07/06/2016', 'dd/mm/yyyy') presentationdateend from dual)
-- end of mimicking your presentation table with data in it. You wouldn't need this subquery as you have the table; see SQL below.
select presentationid,
       presentationday,
       to_char(next_day(presentationdatestart -1, presentationday) + 7*(level - 1), 'DD-MM-YYYY') list_date
from   presentation
connect by prior presentationid = presentationid
           and prior sys_guid() is not null
           and next_day(presentationdatestart -1, presentationday) + 7*(level - 1) <= presentationdateend
order by next_day(presentationdatestart -1, presentationday) + 7*(level - 1),
         presentationid;

PRESENTATIONID PRESENTATIONDAY LIST_DATE 
-------------- --------------- ----------
           622 Monday          02-05-2016
           623 Tuesday         03-05-2016
           624 Wednesday       04-05-2016
           625 Thursday        05-05-2016
           622 Monday          09-05-2016
           623 Tuesday         10-05-2016
           624 Wednesday       11-05-2016
           625 Thursday        12-05-2016
           622 Monday          16-05-2016
           623 Tuesday         17-05-2016
           624 Wednesday       18-05-2016
           625 Thursday        19-05-2016
           622 Monday          23-05-2016
           623 Tuesday         24-05-2016
           624 Wednesday       25-05-2016
           625 Thursday        26-05-2016
           622 Monday          30-05-2016
           623 Tuesday         31-05-2016
           624 Wednesday       01-06-2016
           625 Thursday        02-06-2016
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But Why do I have to use `fmDay` and remove the `trim()`?

Comment: Because a) it's easier to read/maintain, but b) it's one less function call; it uses the built-in functionality of to_char(). That'll aid performance, even if it's just a tiny bit. It does the same job as the trim does, just y'know, at the same time as producing the string. You don't *have* to use it, just like you don't *have* to start your car by using its starter motor (i.e. a bump start), but it's convenient to.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
TO_CHAR(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta,'DD-MM-YYYY','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN' ) LIST_DATE
```

instead of

```
A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta LIST_DATE
```

this formats your date

**updated answer** for your new challenge:

```
select * from (
  select A.presentationID,
       A.PRESENTATIONDAY,


          TO_CHAR(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta,'DD-MM-YYYY','NLS_CALENDAR=GREGORIAN') LIST_DATE,
    row_number() over (partition by presentationID,PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta
order by presentationID,PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta) r
    from 
      PRESENTATION A, 
      (
         select level-1 as delta 
         from dual 
         connect by level-1 <= (
           select max(PRESENTATIONDATEEND- PRESENTATIONDATESTART) from PRESENTATION
         )
      )
    where A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta <= A.PRESENTATIONDATEEND
    and
      a.presentationday = trim(to_char(A.PRESENTATIONDATESTART+delta, 'Day'))

    )
    order by r
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time. What does this query will do? I tried and I am getting a missing right parenthesis error.

Comment: Sorry I forgot one ' at the end of my answer. Use updated answer. The TO_CHAR function formats a date to char type. The first parameter is date the second one is the format of display and the third one is the calendar type

Comment: Thank you for the format.. But I still cant organize the query result as how I desired :)

Comment: Can you please put your result after using my answer?

Comment: use partition by for sorting based on the partitions

Comment: Hmm I am sorry. Still getting another error : `ORA-30485: missing ORDER BY expression in the window specification`

Comment: I fixed it check now

Comment: sorry not having Oracle installed is a big problem. play with different value of partition by such as partition by 1 for example or different columns for order by in it.